# Transformation from XML to new XML including arguments using C# and XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, file-io

I have a C# Console Application that is bulk transforming around 100 XML files to a different markup using the XSLT document **Transformer.xsl**. Each of these XML files contains a hierarchy of topics that are assigned an ID based on the documents title and it's hierarchal position, e.g.

```
<topic id="BSAR_1.5.2">...some content...</topic>
```

To do this I am using the **GetFileNameWithoutExtension** C# method to get the file name and use it as the ID by passing it through an **XSLCompliedTransform** as a argument.

I know that the argument works from inside the XSL document, as it has been tested using Oxygen, and I know that without the argument the XSL transformer runs as follows in C#.

```
//create XSLT complied transformer
            XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();

//load in xslt
            xslTrans.Load(xslPath);string fileExtension = Path.GetFileName(xmlPath);

            string output= (pathDITA+"/DITA_"+fileExtension);

            //Add arguments for TopicID
            //XsltArgumentList argXSLT = new XsltArgumentList();
            //String fileID = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlPath);
            //argXSLT.AddParam("topicID","",fileID);

//convert XML document
            xslTrans.Transform(xmlPath, output);
```

where pathDITA is a variable within the application for where the files are output to, and the arguments section has been commented out.

My issue stands at what Transformer to use when wanting to convert from an XML to an XML including arguments. Currently the transformer method used is **XslCompiledTransform.Transform(string URI, string ResultsFile)**. I am struggling to find a version of this that allows an argument in the middle while still outputting to an XML file directly in the C# resource library.

Simply, what method (or process) would be needed to mimic

```
xslTrans.Transform(xmlPath,argXSLT,output);
```

where *XMLpath* and *output* are both XML files, and *argsXSLT* is the argument being passed in, as the current version returns a type error. Example XML & XSLT will be added if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you head on over to MSDN, you should see the various overloaded versions of the Transform method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform.aspx

So, you should see although it allows `Transform(String, String)` there isn't a `Transform(String, XSLTArgumentList, String)`. What you could use though, for example, is `Transform(String, XsltArgumentList, XmlWriter)`

```
    // Create the XslCompiledTransform and load the stylesheet.
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(xslPath);

    string fileExtension = Path.GetFileName(xmlPath);
    string output = (pathDITA+"/DITA_"+fileExtension);

    XsltArgumentList argXSLT = new XsltArgumentList();
    String fileID = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlPath);
    argXSLT.AddParam("topicID","",fileID);

    using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(output))
    {
        xslt.Transform(xmlPath, argXSLT, w);
    }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163439.aspx for an example of this method.

Comment: I would suggest to use `XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(output, xslt.OutputSettings)` to have the same behavior as with `Transform(string, string)` where the XSLT processor serializes according to the `xsl:output` directive in the XSLT code.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen, using just the XmlWriter was throwing an exception, but your addition solved that problem.